# Как с помощью тега select при выборе option вывести нужный div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как с помощью тега select при выборе option можно вывести нужный div?

```html
<select>
  <option value="one">Один</option>
  <option value="two">Два</option>
  <option value="three">Три</option>
</select>
<div id="one">Текст 1</div>
<div id="two">Текст 2</div>
<div id="three">Текст 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#select').change(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="option">Выбрать / Всё спрятать</option>
  <option value="one">Один</option>
  <option value="two">Два</option>
  <option value="three">Три</option>
</select>
<div id="one" class="hide">Текст 1</div>
<div id="two" class="hide">Текст 2</div>
<div id="three" class="hide">Текст 3</div>
```